# Time-Series analysis with daily measurements

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, interaction

I am having troubles with an analysis and would be grateful for your comments.

Design:
There were several outcomes measured in a large sample over time (i.e., once a day for three months). The outcomes were all questionnaires and give a score each.

What I want to find out:
The individuals participating are different in one dichotomous predictor variable. I want to analyse if their courses in scores over time are different across the two subgroups.

My idea:
Apply mixed models with dependent variable: 'score from the questionnaire' and independent variables: 'time', the dichotomous 'predictor', and the 'baseline value of the outcome score' as adjustment. I would also include 'random intercepts' per ID. So in short: Score ~ time + predictor + baseline score + (1|subject). I would repeat this model for every questionnaire measured.

My concerns:

1. Is my idea appropriate given the design?
2. Would it make sense to also fit a time*predictor interaction and compare the models with likelihood ratio tests?